# Android: Get Notified when the current Mode inside AudioManager gets changed

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

In Android I need to get notified when the current **audio mode** gets changed.

I can get this value through [getMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getMode()) but this is polling.

I don't want to poll every few seconds.

What are my options?

(Please note that I'm not asking about ringerMode)

Comment: did you try listening for AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION?

Comment: "Please note that I'm not asking about ringerMode"

Answer (score 4):

You can use [AudioFocus](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html) for devices running Android OS version 2.2 and higher, preassuming your app is also playing audio.

You can register for audio focus changes and then listen `onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange)` method. By this way you will be notified of audio mode changes as well as other audio focus changes. I hope this helps.

You can also use [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) to listen phone states changes and corresponding audio modes.

Comment: can you give an example of how this can be implemented?

Comment: You can find the implementation with explanations about the audio focus here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus

But it can be used only when we request the audio focus for your app.

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

> interface `AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener`
>
> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the audio focus of the system is updated.

setting this would give you use of `onAudioFocusChange` method.
This would detect Mode changes among other things.

Answer (score -2):

Try this in kotlin

In call i am using the timer for update the call time .I use the code inside the timer

```
 val am = context!!.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
                        val mode = am.mode
    
                        if (AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL == mode) {
                            // device is in a telephony call
                        } else if (AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION == mode) {
                            Log.e("MODE -","IN_COMMUNICATION")
                            // device is in communiation mode, i.e. in a VoIP or video call
                        } else if (AudioManager.MODE_RINGTONE == mode) {
                            // device is in ringing mode, some incoming is being signalled
                            if(AttendMeetingActivity.meetingManager!=null){
                                AttendMeetingActivity.meetingManager!!.onIncomingCall()
                            }else if( IncomingCallActivity.callControlManager!=null){
                                IncomingCallActivity!!.callControlManager!!.doHangUpCall()
                            }
                        } else {
                            // device is in normal mode, no incoming and no audio being played
                        }
```